# Eager-loading of matrix field with getPage

Tags: matrix, eager-loading

Can anyone provide a working example to extend the following code (add support for matrix block named "copy") and allow getPage usage:

```
{% set entries = craft.entries({
   section: ['news'],
   order: 'postDate desc',
   limit: 5,
   with: [
     ['assets', { kind: 'image' }]
   ]
}) %}


{% for content in entry.contentBuilder.type('copy').limit(1) %}
   {{ content.copy.getPage(1) }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Update after Brad's comment since the `with` part seems to be ok - by the way thank you, it is another good example that you never stop learning.

<s>I never saw that `with` attribute in a `ElementCriteriaModel` and after several searches I could not find any use of that attribute in craft (Please correct me if I'm wrong)</s> the rest should be fine.

Instead of the `.limit(1)` you could do the following

```
{% set content = entry.contentBuilder.type('copy').first() %}
```

The `getPage()` function only exists in the class `RichTextData` maybe you have a different fieldType? Otherwise you could just do `{{ content.copy }}` as well to display the text in that field.

All in all it would be a good idea to tell us a little bit more about your goal, your fields and your errors. Your description is a little bit insufficient in my opinion

Comment: The `with` eager loading syntax looks O.K. to me https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/eager-loading-elements#defining-custom-parameters-on-eager-loaded-elements